# Python - How to merge a list in a list to a single list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x, data-structures

I currently have a list like this:

`[3, 4, ['x', 'y', 'z'], 5]`

and want to make it to

`[3, 4, 'x', 'y', 'z', 5]`

New beginner at this, and tried searching around, but couldn't find anything I could understand.

Comment: Just google `flatten list of lists in python`. Definitely a duplicate.

Comment: Why doesn't your attempt to solve it work?  Maybe we can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[3, 4, ['x', 'y', 'z'], 5]
nl=[]
for x in l:
    if not isinstance(x,int):
        for y in x:
            nl.append(y)
    else:
        nl.append(x)

print(nl)
```

One liner

```
l=[3, 4, ['x', 'y', 'z'], 5]
nl=[];[nl.extend([x] if isinstance(x,int) else x) for x in l]
```

It is not flatening list of list because the given one is combination of list and int

Comment: [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) "...is recommended for testing the type of an object..."

Comment: Your "one-liner" is an example of when NOT to use list comprehensions. Do not mix imperative techniques (mutating a data structure: i.e. `list.exend`) with functional constructs, i.e. list comprehensions. Also, it is generally considered unpythonic to use multiple statements per line, seperated by a semicolon, like that. Readability counts.